# C# WPF listView not real time updating when adding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have a listView binded to a class:

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="277" Margin="23,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="750">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="#" Width="20" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding execNumber}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Function" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding currentFunction}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Message" Width="300"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding pcdMessage}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Event Type" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding pcdEventType}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Event" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding pcdEvent}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Timing" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding strTime}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

while in Codebehind the class is

```
private class PcdStatus
    {
        public PcdStatus(int _execNumber, String _currentFunction, String _pcdMessage, Helper.ePcdEventType _pcdEventType, Helper.ePcdEvent _pcdEvent,String _strTime )
        {
            execNumber = _execNumber;
            currentFunction = _currentFunction;
            pcdMessage = _pcdMessage;
            pcdEventType = _pcdEventType;
            pcdEvent = _pcdEvent;
            strTime = _strTime;
        }
        public int execNumber { get; set; }
        public String currentFunction { get; set; }
        public String pcdMessage { get; set; }
        public Helper.ePcdEventType pcdEventType { get; set; }
        public Helper.ePcdEvent pcdEvent { get; set; }
        public String strTime { get; set; }
    }
```

the class is updated via event:

```
private void MyPcd_OnStatusChange(string _currentFunction, string _PCDMessage, Helper.ePcdEventType _pcdEventType, Helper.ePcdEvent _pcdEvent)
    {
        String strTime;
        if (lastTime == default(DateTime))       
            strTime = "---";
        else
        {
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - lastTime;
            strTime = ts.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000")+ "\"";
        }
        lastTime = DateTime.Now;

        PcdStatus newStatus = new PcdStatus(execNumber, _currentFunction, _PCDMessage, _pcdEventType, _pcdEvent, strTime);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.ocList.Add(newStatus)));
        //ocList.Add(newStatus);           
    }
```

the class update is done properly but not in real time. I have added a console.Beep() that warns me when the an event is fired from a library. So Event from Library ---> My_PcdOnStatusChange ---> ocList.Add ---> listView updated. 
I expected an update per each beep but the listView is updated only at the end of all the s/r.

**EDIT** Sorry forgot to mention that the ocList below stands for:

```
 ObservableCollection<PcdStatus> ocList = new ObservableCollection<PcdStatus>();
```

**EDIT2** I am pretty sure that the problem doesn't rely on the ListView or the binding itself. I have added a property which changes a picture. Red when program started and green when idle.

```
  private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;               
            if (value)
                imgBusy.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => imgBusy.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"../../Resources/redBall.png", UriKind.Relative))));
            else
                imgBusy.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => imgBusy.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"../../Resources/greenBall.png", UriKind.Relative))));
        }
    }
```

The expected behaviour is:

```
idle --> green
started ---> red
terminated ---> green
```

while its behaviour is:

```
idle ---> green
started --->green
midway ---> red
terminated --->green.
```

I am new with WPF in winforms there was a Mainform.Update. Is there something similar here?

Thanx for any help
Patrick

Comment: The Dispatcher doesn't guarantee when your action is invoked.  Besides, you don't even specify a [DispatcherPriority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx).  Try setting the priority to `Send` and see if that helps.  FYI, it will never be perfect as the message loop can never process UI events in anything near "real time".

Comment: ocList  may be an observable collection but your code doesn't show any binding to it, where are you setting ListView.ItemSource = {Binding ocList  }?

Comment: `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous. Use `Invoke` for synchronous dispatcher calls.

Comment: @Clemens please see my edit2 I use invoke but that doesnt' change.

Comment: @MikeT sorry my bad I have it  lvInfo.ItemsSource = ocList; but please see my edit2

Comment: @Will you might be right!!! I don't want anything in "real" real time just something as close as possible. Alas I have added System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send but that has not changed. As I said in WindowsForms there was a Mainform.Update() isn't there something similar in WPF?

Comment: Meh, not sure. One other approach you could try is to set up a DispatcherTimer in your UI which will allow you to update the UI on a near real-time basis...  Hard to see where your issue lies :/

Comment: WPF is specifically designed to be binding driven, there for any data assignment that doesn't implement binding on a Notify object will act in a unpredictable way, if in the code behind you are assigning your collection to the item source then it wont be bound and you wont get the updating occuring. in WPF your code behind file should be empty apart from event handlers and even those should be minimal

Answer (score 3):

you need to bind the ItemSource property to a collection that implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

the simplest of these is [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

PcdStatus should also implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want property changes to update